# My wife left Islam so we seperated for a few months now she has returned to the deen can we get back together now

Tags: nikah, fiqh, apostasy

My wife dexided to apostate so I seperated from her and left .  She after a few months has returned to islam. Is it HALAL for me to return to her?

Answer (score 1):

Apostasy severs the nikah. You would need to remarry after she returned to Islam.

**References:**

> (وَارْتِدَادُ أَحَدِهِمَا) أَيْ الزَّوْجَيْنِ (فَسْخٌ) فَلَا يُنْقِصُ عَدَدًا (عَاجِلٌ)
>
> <sup>— [الدر المختار وحاشية ابن عابدين](https://al-maktaba.org/book/21613/1475#p2)</sup>